# How to generate UITextFields dynamically with different name and accessing it from another place?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, uitextfield, dynamic

I have an iPhone application in which there are dynamically generated textfields to capture a value of product quantity. The default quantity is 1. I have generated textfields like this

```
for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
    UITextField *i=[[UITextField alloc]init];
    i.frame=CGRectMake(90, Yposqtytextfield, 60, 30);
    i.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    [self.scrollview addSubview:i];

    i.delegate=self;
    i.text=@"1";
    i.tag=i;
    [appDelegate.qtyArray addObject:i.text];
}
```

But I want values of quantities in next page. For that I have taken this qtyarray. Now  the user is allowed to change quantity. So how can I change the value of quantity in the array. as declaration of textfield is local to that loop. So at next page navigation how can i get the values of all these textfields?

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextField *aField = (UITextField*)[appDelegate.qtyArray objectAtIndex:0]
```

it should be

```
NSString *aValue = [appDelegate.qtyArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

because he is adding value of textfield not the textfield object itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can access your qtyArray anywhere in the application. Since application delegate is singleton class. You can access  value like this

```
NSString *aValue = [appDelegate.qtyArray objectAtIndex:0];
```